# Can you change a Unity theme?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, themes

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so this might not make sense (?) but I see a lot of GNOME Shell themes online, and they make people's computers look awesome, but I like the look of the Unity environment more, so I don't want to switch to the GNOME desktop... is there a way to either install GNOME shell themes without removing Unity, or is there such thing as a Unity theme? (I haven't been able to find one or an answer to this...)

Comment: Shell themes are only for gnome shell, if you mean gtk3 themes you can easily add them creating a .themes directory in your home and extract them there.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to
`System Settings/Appearance/Look`
you can select one of the default themes.
Of course, you can search for unity themes online. I have never done it until now. There are some examples on this site:

http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/ubuntu/best-ubuntu-1404-trusty-themes

It seems that you should install unity-tweak-tool first:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

and then look for themes online, and add the repository, install the theme, and then switch to it using unity-tweak-tool.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme
```